# jquery tools overlay with external page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery tools overlay, and I'm loading an external page into overlay. When I click a overlay page's button, can I invoke a method which is defined in the background page?

Comment: your one sentence question invites more questions than you are asking. Answer depends on how page is loaded, where script is coming from and.... provide some code and better explanation